# How to set a slider to fix to positions?

Tags: java, javafx, slider

I have a slider and I require it to fix to int numbers 1-23. So if the user were to move it from 1 they would end up on any number that is 1-23, unlike a double value. The purpose of this slider is to be a clock, you drag it and different times appear.

My first attempt:

```
private final int MIN_CHANGE = 1;
....

timeSlider.setMax(23);

....

timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (!timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
        if (Math.abs(newValue.intValue()) > MIN_CHANGE) {
            timeSlider.setValue(newValue.intValue());
        }
    }
});
```

This more or less works but only for clicking, not for dragging.

How could I get a slider to fix to whole numbers like 1-23 when dragging if the getValue is a double?

Another problem I face is when dragging the pm/am changing is not sudden.

```
timeSlider.valueChangingProperty().addListener((obs, wasChanging, isChanging) -> {
    if (isChanging) {
        if(timeSlider.getValue() < 12.99) {
            labelTest.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.0f:00am", timeSlider.valueProperty()));
        } else {
            labelTest.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.0f:00pm", timeSlider.valueProperty()));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you are looking for [Slider#blockIncrementProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#blockIncrementProperty)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. What about the am/pm update? How do I get it to update when dragging, not just clicking? Right now I can drag from the start to finish and the am/pm won't change unless I click on any value after 13.

Comment: *the am/pm won't change unless I click on any value after 13*. I don't get this. Can you explain what is happening at your end.

Comment: I meant I can drag the slider from 0 to 15 and the binding would stay on am, unless I click on any value after 13 which is only when the binding would change to pm. I just fixed this however by doing this in `valueProperty()` instead of `valueChangingProperty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try settings `snapToTicks` to true and the major tick spacing to 23:

```
timeSlider.setSnapToTicks(true);
timeSlider.setMajorTickUnit(23.0);
timeSlider.setBlockIncrement(23.0);
timeSlider.setMinorTickCount(0.0); // Disable minor ticks
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it snap to numbers I used the blockIncrement, majorTickUnit and snapToTicks provided in the FXML scene builder which I didn't notice before until now, thanks to ItachiUchiha.

For reference I used the following settings

```
min="1.0"
max="23.0" 
blockIncrement="1.0" 
majorTickUnit="1.0" 
minorTickCount="0" 
showTickMarks="true" 
snapToTicks="true"
```

Lastly, to fix my issue with am/pm not updating I changed my method for am/pm binding to the following

```
timeSlider.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (timeSlider.isValueChanging()) {
        if (newValue.intValue() < 12) {
            labelTest.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.0f:00am", timeSlider.valueProperty()));
        } else {
            labelTest.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("%.0f:00pm", timeSlider.valueProperty()));
        }
    }
});
```